# Probability and number of trials

Tags: probability, self-study

I have a 50% chance of winning a game.  I can either play the game 10, 20, or 100 times.  I need to win at least 70% of the games.  How many times, if there is a difference, should I play the game?

Comment: This was a question on a test, and I had an intense debate with one of my friends over it.

Comment: You should clearly identify the source of it in your own question; (note, for example, that we have no easy way to tell the difference between a test you had in the past and *one you're doing right now*... )

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself (what did you think the answer was and why?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play the game as few times as possible.

Your expected number of wins follows the binomial distribution with p=0.5. That is to say, if you play 200 games, you're expected to win 100. Since you want to beat these expectations, you want to maximize the variance which is equivalent to reducing the number of trials.

Comment: Or what amounts to the same thing, play the game until you've won at least 70% of the time or $n=100$ and then quit.